# Fractal Net Evolution Approach (FNEA) Citation

Tags: remote-sensing, ecognition

I've been looking for some original source to cite for FNEA (Fractal Net Evolution Approach), instead of just citing eCognition.  Does anyone know of a paper on the origin of FNEA?  My searches just turn up papers using FNEA.  Perhaps the FNEA name was coined later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, FNEA and "multiresolution segmentation" are the same. The authors did not publish their full method (how it is optimized) but there are two proceedings that could be used for scientific citation (especially the second).

> @INPROCEEDINGS{Baatz1999,   author = {Baatz, M. and Schäpe, A.},
>   title = {Object-Oriented and Multi-Scale Image Analysis in Semantic
>   Networks},   booktitle = {Proc. of the 2nd International Symposium on
>   Operationalization of     Remote Sensing},   year = {1999},   pages =
>   {--},   address = {Enschede, ITC},
>
> }
>
> @INPROCEEDINGS{Baatz2000,   author = {Baatz, M. and Schäpe, A.},
>   title = {Multiresolution Segmentation - an optimization approach for
>   high  quality multi-scale image segmentation},   booktitle =
>   {Angewandte Geographische Informationsverarbeitung XII},   year =
>   {2000},   editor = {Strobl, J. and Blaschke, T. and Griesebner, G.},
>   pages = {12-23},   publisher = {Wichmann-Verlag, Heidelberg},
>   chapter = {Multiresolution Segmentation - an optimization approach for
>   high  quality multi-scale image segmentation},    }

as a remark, "Schäpe" is sometimes written "Schaepe"